# Sign in hashing user input

Tags: php, hash, passwords

I'm not much of a PHP programmer, but I'm trying to work out how to read a hashed password when a user signs into a website.  I have saved the hashed password with the following PHP:

```
     $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

     $key = $pass;
     $string = $pass;

     $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
     $decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");

     mysql_select_db("db", $con);

     $sql="INSERT INTO members_tbl (email, pass, registration_date)
     VALUES ('$email','$encrypted', now())";
```

I'm not sure how to read what the user has inputed and check wether its the same as the decrypted variable and if true sign them in.  Here is my attempt:

```
//Sanitize the POST values
     $signin_email = clean($_POST['signin_email']);
     $signin_pass = clean($_POST['signin_pass']);

     //Input Validations
     if($signin_email == '') {
          $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username missing';
          $errflag = true;
     }
     if($signin_pass == '') {
          $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
          $errflag = true;
     }

     //If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
     if($errflag) {
          $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
          session_write_close();
          header("location: index.php");
          exit();
     }

     $pass = $signin_pass;

     $key = $pass;
     $string = $pass;

     $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
     $decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");

     //Create query
     $qry = "SELECT * FROM members_tbl WHERE email='$signin_email' AND pass='$decrypted'";

     //do something
```

Comment: *COUGH* http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php *COUGH*

Comment: Also see Openwall's [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/). Its hardened for a number of attacks.

Comment: What the hell are encrypting to justify using `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`? That's military grade encryption right there.

Comment: Thanks Andrei P, can you point me in the direction of a better example?

Comment: You are saving an encrypted password and and select it with the decrypted?

Comment: Pro tip 1) never try to setup your own hashing scheme ever. Pro tip 2) encrypting is not what you want to do when storing passwords. Just use the first linked native php functions or the [compat lib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) if you php version doesn't support it

Answer (score -2):

Just compare the hashed password in the database with the hashed password you create on userlogin, if they are the same its a match.

Comment: $qry = "SELECT * FROM members_tbl WHERE email='$signin_email' AND pass='$decrypted'";  should be $qry = "SELECT * FROM members_tbl WHERE email='$signin_email' AND pass='$encrypted'";